# Access javascript object attribute in dynamically generated handler function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following Javascript file, where some html is generated dynamically:

```
(function ($){

NunoEstradaViwer: {
  settings: {
  total: 0,
  format: "",
  num: 0;
  },
  init: function (el, options) {
  if (!el.length) { return false; }
    this.options = $.extend({}, this.settings, options);
    this.itemIndex =0;
    this.container = el;

    this.total = this.options.total;
    this.format = ".svg";
    this.num = 0;
    this.generateHtml(el);
  },
  generateHtml: function(container){
        var bnext = document.createElement('input');
        bnext.setAttribute("type", "button");
        bnext.setAttribute("id", "bnext");
        bnext.onclick = this.nextImage();
        bnext.setAttribute("value", "Next");
        container.appendChild(bnext);

  },
  nextImage: function(){
     this.num++;


 }
 });
```

What I wanted to do was to access the `NunoEstradaViwer` attribute `num` inside the `nextImage` function but instead the this object points to the `bnext` button.

Do you know how I can manage that?

Comment: from where is the `nextImage` called?

Comment: The NunoestradaViewer is an extension of a div. The button "bnext" is added to that div. When the "bnext" is clicked the function "nextImage" is called

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@rahen, I tried your sugestions but unfortunately none worked.
What I found out that worked for me was a solution envolving jquery. I did the following:

```
generateHtml: function(container){
    var bnext = document.createElement('input');
    bnext.setAttribute("type", "button");
    bnext.setAttribute("id", "bnext");
    bnext.setAttribute("value", "Next");
    container.appendChild(bnext);

$("#bnext").bind('click',{viewer: this}, function(event) {
            event.data.viewer.nextImage();
        });

},
nextImage: function(){
 this.num++;
}
```

And this way I can access the value of num and it is changed for the NunoEstradaViwer.

Comment: this is smarter way.
anyway, my demo is available [here / demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hd2Dt/1/)

Comment: I appreciated your help a lot. This is a recreation of my problem that is a bit more complex, and probably there is something diferent that makes the solution you presented me not work

Answer (score 1):

check the [link](http://jsfiddle.net/hd2Dt/1/)

```
bnext.onclick = this.nextImage; // not bnext.onclick = this.nextImage();
```

another thing is

```
NunoEstradaViwer.num++ ;  // instead of this.num++
```